# Spatiotemporal mixed-effects in R: Too large groups in correlation structure

Tags: r, correlation, mixed-models, nlme, spatial-regression

I am trying to fit a mixed-effect model with a spatiotemporal correlation structure using `lme {nlme}`.
The data comprises 37936 lon (*x*) + lat (*y*) grid-cells (18968 male + 18968 female) with density (kde), above/below long-term average rainfall (*rainAB*) and distance to water (*wDist*) repeated every year from 2001 to 2010 (*yearF*=10).
I want to model how *kde* is influenced by *rainAB* and *wDist* for male vs. female animals, while allowing each *sexF* to have its own intercept and its own slope for *yearF*, which in turn are all correlated over space (*x+y*) and time (*yearF*).
The model runs fine with a small dataset (n=3780) but there are `Too large groups in the correlation structure` with the larger dataset (n=379360). I would appreciate any advice on how to deal with this please - See reproducible example below.

```
# LOAD LIBRARIES
library(nlme)
library(car)
library(dplyr)
library(ggstatsplot)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# SMALL DATASET
set.seed(1)
(nGrid_s = 189) #Number of 1km grid cells in study area
(nYrs = 10) #Number of years
(nGrps = 2) #Number of groups i.e. male and female

dat_s = data.frame(x=rep(seq(from=283, to=401, length.out=nGrid_s),each=nYrs),
                   y=rep(seq(from=7176, to=7529, length.out=nGrid_s),each=nYrs),
                   yearF=as.factor(rep(2001:2010, nGrid_s)),
                   sexF=as.factor(rep(c('male','female'), each=nGrid_s*nYrs)),
                   kde=runif(nGrid_s*nYrs, 0, 8),
                   rainAB=runif(nGrid_s*nYrs, -70, 247),
                   wDist=runif(nGrid_s*nYrs, 0, 14))
str(dat_s)

# LME WITH SMALL DATASET (n=3780)
lmeS = lme(kde~rainAB/sexF+wDist/sexF, #What about how rainAB affects wDist
           # random=~y+x|yearF,
           random=~yearF|sexF,
           correlation=corSpatial(form=~x+y|sexF/yearF),
           control=lmeControl(maxIter=50, msMaxIter=50, niterEM=50, opt='optim',msVerbose=TRUE),
           method="REML",
           data=dat_s)
summary(lmeS)
Anova(lmeS, type=c("III")) 
ggcoefstats(x = lmeS, title = "Small LME mixed-effects model")
##############################################################################################

# GENERATE LARGE DATASET
set.seed(2)
(nGrid_l = 18968) #Number of 1km grid cells in study area

dat_l = data.frame(x=rep(seq(from=283, to=401, length.out=nGrid_l),each=nYrs),
                   y=rep(seq(from=7176, to=7529, length.out=nGrid_l),each=nYrs),
                   yearF=as.factor(rep(2001:2010, nGrid_l)),
                   sexF=as.factor(rep(c('male','female'), each=nGrid_l*nYrs)),
                   kde=runif(nGrid_l*nYrs, 0, 8),
                   rainAB=runif(nGrid_l*nYrs, -70, 247),
                   wDist=runif(nGrid_l*nYrs, 0, 14))

# LME WITH LARGE DATASET (n=379360)
lmeL = lme(kde~rainAB/sexF+wDist/sexF, #What about how rainAB affects wDist
           # random=~y+x|yearF,
           random=~yearF|sexF,
           correlation=corSpatial(form=~x+y|sexF/yearF),
           control=lmeControl(maxIter=50, msMaxIter=50, niterEM=50, opt='optim',msVerbose=TRUE),
           method="REML",
           data=dat_l)
# Error: 'sumLenSq := sum(table(groups)^2)' = 1.43914e+10 is too large.
# Too large or no groups in your correlation structure?
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```